# Help needed with the derivation of a Levi civita symbol identity

Tags: tensors

The given identity is:

$\epsilon_{ijk} = ½(i-j)(j-k)(k-i)$

Can anyone help me where to start with this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hi Kritika. How do you normally define the Levi-Civita symbol? For me, it is given by $\epsilon_{ijk} = 0$ if two or more of the indices are equal, while for distinct indices $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the sign of the permutation $(i\ j\ k)$. You can verify that the expression on the right hand side satisfies both of these properties, and hence is equal to $\epsilon_{ijk}$. Let me know if you are using a different definition or have trouble verifying one of the properties.